# NodeJS to consume Kafka messages from Java producer

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I am trying to consume a Kafka message produced by a Java application with schema defintion using avro.

```
const { Kafka } = require('kafkajs');
const axios = require('axios');
const avroRegistry = require('avro-schema-registry');
const avro = require('avsc');
const { Partitioners } = require('kafkajs');

...

  await consumer.subscribe({ topic, fromBeginning: true });

    async function handleMessage(message) {
      try {
        const messageAsString = JSON.stringify(message);
        const messageObject = JSON.parse(messageAsString);
        const avroMessage = messageObject.message.value;

        console.log('messageObject:', messageObject);
        console.log('avroMessage:', avroMessage);
        const buffer = Buffer.from(avroMessage.data);
        console.log('buffer:', buffer);
        
        // Use Avro to decode the buffer
        //let type = avro.Type.forSchema(yourAvroSchema);
        let decoded = type.fromBuffer(buffer);
      } catch (error) {
        if (error instanceof avro.AvroError) {
          // Handle specific Avro decoding errors
          console.error('Avro decoding error:', error.message);
        } else {
          console.error('Unexpected error decoding message:', error);
        }
      }
    }

    await consumer.connect();
    await consumer.run({
      eachMessage: handleMessage,
    });
```

I can only access the "avroMessage" variable but not able to decode the Buffer.

I got the following error

```
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2024-02-25T20:04:57.433Z","logger":"kafkage":"[Runner] Error when calling eachMessage","topic":"my-toipc","partition":0,"offset":"98","stack":"TypeError: Rside of 'instanceof' is not an object\n    at Runner.handleMessage [asge]
```

Note that the same message can be consumed in Java. And Java is using org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.Record when producing the message.

Comment: If the Java code uses schema registry, then this code will need to, as well. The data from the buffer isn't directly Avro data that can be deserialized

Comment: Yes, I have defined const avroRegistry = require('avro-schema-registry'). How do I use it in the consumer?

Comment: That's just an import... The documentation shows a decode function https://kafkajs.github.io/confluent-schema-registry/docs/usage-with-kafkajs